# Force DOMXpath - php - to return utf-8 results

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, domdocument, domxpath

First off, I know this problem was signaled before, but the solutions do not apply to my case

Here is the url
http://www.astagiudiziaria.com/beni/porzione_di_rustico_e_terreni_agricoli/index.html

The page says its charset is ISO-8859-1, but it cannot be since it has the EURO sign on it. Chrome browser identifies it as windows-1252

I used

```
$file = str_replace('charset=iso-8859-1', 'charset=utf-8', $file);
$file = iconv('windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $file);
```

and save it and my text editor says it is UTF-8 encoded

Then I use

```
$doc2->loadHTML($file);
$doc2->saveHTMLFile('ggg.html');
```

and also my text editor says it is UTF-8 encoded 
But http://i-tools.org/charset says this file, ggg.html is actually ASCII !

Nonetheless, inside it things look as expected, even though they are using html encodings , like  Pré  or proprietà

The xpath queries return garbage data, like 
instead of Pré is PrÃ©
instead of € is â‚¬Â

I have tried the solutions suggested around here without any success
I think it's about how php is dealing with libxml, since in ruby it works flawlessly - also using libxml through curb gem - problem being that my client wants a php script

Comment: `The xpath queries return garbage data, like instead of Pré is PrÃ© instead of € is â‚¬Â` - where do you see this? In a web browser? Did you "inform" the browser that _your_ document is utf-8 encoded?

Comment: Not in a browser. The data is meant to be saved in a database. I just print_r the array with results into a file. My text editor says that this dump file is ASCII, not UTF-8 as I would expect.

Comment: if anyone can make something out of this http://www.xmlsoft.org/encoding.html

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9f042ry08ccb73/ttt.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick glance, and the way I see it the site outputs mixed encoding.

It is `iso-8859-1` with a mixed-in `windows-1252` `€` sign (I think).
Thats why the browser gets confused (but somehow handles it).

No idea how you would proceed here, apart from asking them to fix their site or alternativly do some bit-fiddling.

the `Pré is PrÃ©` breaks because you attemt to `windows-1252->utf8` transcode what actually is `iso-8859-1` stuff (I suppose).

Comment: I have done lots and lots of things. I did get the correct Pré in some instances , still there were other issues , as you can see in the dropbox file. I need a solution where everything is how it should be, as my ruby script demonstrates it is possible - and , in ruby, very easy

Comment: here is the ggg.html file https://www.dropbox.com/s/k1kdnw16h1kor45/ggg.html?dl=0 it is how the libxml internally parsed the DOM It looks good !  but is ASCII , not UTF-8 and therein lies the problem Xpath returns text data, not HTML, so the ASCII cannot represent it How can I force the document to treat the document internally as UTF-8, as it does 99% of time ? Why in this instance it does not treat the document as UTF-8 ?

Comment: the ggg.html file is ASCII with htmlentites; `Xpath returns text data, not HTML,` what ? - It cannot treat it as utf-8 because the source has mixed encoding, you cannot treat it as anything, except broken. (unless my answer is wrong)